# Python execute playsound in separate thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-playsound

I need to play a sound in my Python program so I used **playsound** module for that:

```
def playy():
    playsound('beep.mp3')
```

How can I modify this to run inside main method as a new thread?
I need to run this method inside the main method if a condition is true. When it is false the thread needs to stop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use threading library :

```
from threading import Thread
T = Thread(target=playy) # create thread
T.start() # Launch created thread
```

Answer (score 8):

You may not have to worry about using a thread.  You can simply call playsound as follows:

```
def playy():  
    playsound('beep.mp3', block = False)
```

This will allow the program to keep running without waiting for the sound play to finish.

Comment: Not supported yet on all platforms, e.g. not supported on Linux

Answer (score 2):

As python multi-threading is not really multi-threading ([more on this here](https://realpython.com/python-gil/)), I would suggest using a multi-process for it:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def playy():
    playsound('beep.mp3')


P = Process(name="playsound",target=playy)
P.start() # Inititialize Process
```

can be terminated at will with `P.terminate()`

Comment: You don't want to call the `run()` method directly. That gets called by the `start()`. For example see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class).

Comment: Your right. it was not in my original answer, it was edited in there. removed it.

Comment: I think it depends on the version of python you have and the operating system used.  When I use start(), the function is initialized, but not executed.

Comment: for me terminate doesn't stop it from running, I have to end it from system monitor