# Program is crashing while using playsound module

Tags: python, module

so yeah, i am just making a program which plays music of my favourite game. Now what the thing is that when i call the `playsound` function of `playsound`(module) then, my programs lags and then eventually crashes. Here is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from playsound import playsound
import multiprocessing
class dynastyMusicer(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, screenName=None, baseName=None, className='Tk',
                 useTk=True, sync=False, use=None):
        super().__init__(screenName=screenName, baseName=baseName, className=className, useTk=useTk, sync=sync, use=use) 
        self.title("Dynasty Musicer")
        self.geometry("250x100")
        self.config(background="white")
        chooseL = tk.Label(self, text="Which music to play?", background="white")
        chooseL.place(x=50, y=0)
        ops = ["Dynasty Dojo", "Dynasty Dojo Fight"]
        self.stvar = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.stvar.set("Music")
        self.option = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.stvar, *ops)
        self.option.place(y=30)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text="Play", width=10, command=self.play)
        btn.place(y=70)
        stop = tk.Button(self, text="Stop", width=10, command=self.stop)
        stop.place(x=160,y=70)
    def stop(self):
        multiprocessing.Process(target=playsound, args=(self.stvar.get()+".mp3"))
    def play(self):
        if self.stvar.get() == "Dynasty Dojo":
                playsound(r"path")
        elif self.stvar.get() == "Dynasty Dojo Fight":
            playsound(r"path")
                
dm = dynastyMusicer()
dm.mainloop()
```

also because of this i can't test whether my `stop` function is working or not because when you'll click the play button then yeah, you guessed it, it would crash. if you wanna download the two music file i used, here are the links:

[Dynasty Dojo](https://www.mediafire.com/file/hd2k4akgrzckxy3/10_-_Dynasty_Dojo.mp3/file)

[Dynasty dojo fight](https://www.mediafire.com/file/oh91ac0bh9t23cx/11_-_Dynasty_Dojo_Fight.mp3/file)

Comment: Use: `playsound(r"path",block=True)`. Follow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56678592/13382000

Comment: nope still laggin' and crashing again and again after clicking play. thanks for answering though

Comment: Wait my bad, what I meant was, `block=False` :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things to look at with your code. To being with:

- `tkinter` is single threaded, running it from a separate thread will cause issue, though you can use `multiprocessing` if you can ensure the `tk` objects wont go into the other processes/thread.
- However such pain is not unnecessary in this case, here you will not need to use any of this as `playsound` can be run without blocking the thread, like: `playsound(..., block=False)`
- Also here I noticed a stop button, you cannot stop a started sound with `playsound` so now you have to start looking for some other threaded sound library and `pygame` is the best I can find. Though it has some support issues with files, it should be alright for most cases.

Here is the better code using `pygame` and modifying your current settings:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pygame # pip install pygame

class DynastyMusicer(tk.Tk): # Using Pascal Case notation for class names
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): # Shorten all the optional arguments
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) # or tk.Tk.__init__(....)
        self.title("Dynasty Musicer")
        self.geometry("250x100")
        self.config(background="white")
        
        pygame.init() # Initialize pygame

        chooseL = tk.Label(self, text="Which music to play?", background="white")
        chooseL.place(x=50, y=0)
        
        self.ops = ["Dynasty Dojo", "Dynasty Dojo Fight"]
        self.stvar = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.stvar.set("Music")
        
        self.option = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.stvar, *self.ops)
        self.option.place(y=30)
        
        btn = tk.Button(self, text="Play", width=10, command=self.play)
        btn.place(y=70)
        
        stop = tk.Button(self, text="Stop", width=10, command=self.stop)
        stop.place(x=160,y=70)
    
    def stop(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.stop() # Stop the music being played

    def play(self):
        if self.stvar.get() != 'Music': # If not the default value, then
            pygame.mixer.music.load(rf"{self.stvar.get()}.mp3") # Load the song
            pygame.mixer.music.play() # Play the song
                
dm = DynastyMusicer()
dm.mainloop()
```

Here, your `if` statement is modified to be shorted because you follow [whitelisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelisting) which disables any *invalid* input from going in(except 'Music').

Comment: Well, i didn't add the `__init__` function arguments myself it was just one of  vscode's stupid snippet. i am lazy so i thought who would clear it for me and you did andddddd anyways thanks